# drf isnt accepting data when making a post request with fetch

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Im working with static files and making a soundcloud clone using drf for backend with aws as hosting for the files. when i make a post request with the files the backend returns this error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "name" of relation "cloudsound_song" violates not-null constraint
```

so i console.logged the data to see if it was returning empty or not, it wasn't. it looks like the backend doesnt want to accept the form data, before this i would get a 500 error.

here are my backend files

**app/views.py**

```
class SongViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    content_type ='multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
    serializer_class = SongSerializer
    parser_classes = [parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FormParser, parsers.JSONParser, parsers.FileUploadParser]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

**app/serializers.py**

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    content_type ='multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False )
    image = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    audio_file = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta :
        model = Song
        fields = ('id',  'image', 'name', 'audio_file', 'created_on')
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        song = Song.objects.create(
            name=validated_data.get('name'),
            image=validated_data.get('image'),
            audio_file=validated_data.get('audio_file'),
        )

        song.save()

        return song
```

**app/models.py**

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, )
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='./media/', default='./media/default-cover-art_tVe9r28.png' )
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='./media/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

please let me know if this isnt enough.

i put null=true to see if it was just my form that was wrong or the post request but it wasnt it would post correctly the fields are just null.

```
{
        "id": 31,
        "image": null,
        "name": null,
        "audio_file":null,
        "created_on": "2023-01-07T03:20:55.104324Z"
    },
```

Comment: Did you remember to migrate the db after adding `null=True` ?

Comment: Also, do you have another model called CloudSound?

Comment: @Beikeni i did migrate after adding it, the post request did go through but the fields were null ill add it to my question

Comment: `image`, `audio_file` and `name` either have to have a value or have to have `null=True` in the model declaration. Or they must have a default value declared in the model declaration like you did for `image`

Comment: @Beikeni so i made the changes but the post request still isnt sending through edit: so it does it just doesnt send any data through to the backend i get a error 500

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the related docs but I took a look at a past project and I found this.
Try refactoring your `perform_create` to this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user.id)
```

Comment: so i managed to fix it, it seems it was a front end error on my part which was odd i needed to use formData.append('audio_field', e.target.audio_file.files[0]) which got me the result i wanted.